# PhantomJs onResourceReceived URL decode issue

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, urldecode

I'm creating a web scraping bot in PhantomJs, I'm using onResourceReceived to sniff the  the requests of the site and retrieve them using this simple code:

```
page.onResourceReceived = function(response) 
{
    if (response.url.match("XXXXXXX")) 
    {

        console.log(response.url);
    }

};
```

My problem is that **response.url** automatically update the data to a URL-decoded version of this. I need to check some parameters but instead of receiving something like this :

> xxx.com?...&events=event20%2Cevent4%%2Cevent89%3D7%2Cevent50%2Cevent51%2Cevent52%2Cevent53%2Cevent54%2Cevent55%2Cevent56&...

I get this

> xxx.com?... &events=event20%2Cevent4%2Cevent89%3D7&....

It looks like when %3D is reached it cuts the value and continues to the next property.

Is there a way to access the raw version of this data?
Thanks a lot for the help.